# Multiple lens configuration thickness and distances

Tags: geometric-optics, lenses

Struggling to understand where I should measure lens thickness and distance between lenses from.

I've attached an example multiple lens setup.

For determining individual lenses thickness is it simply the distance between the two outermost points of the lens?

For determining distances between lenses, I understand that if lenses are next to each other thickness/distance is set to zero and that's reasonably obvious in some situations but how does this apply to lenses which overlap like concave and convex lenses side by side or smaller lens within a lens that has a larger radius of curvature etc. The picture attached shows some of these slightly more confusing scenarios and I was wondering whether some have 'negative' distances or not. Some guidance on this would be appreciated as my paraxial ray tracing equations aren't matching what I'm seeing when simulating on phydemo

Cheers [image: multiple lens setup example]

Comment: Even if the marginal ray is towards the top of the lens, do the 'thickness' values come from the centre of the lens/optical axis?

Comment: I've adjusted so that it's thickness through optical axis but still not matching what phydemo is showing me

Comment: Lens thicknesses, for a centered, symmetric, optical system, are measured along the optical axis. You don't state what the discrepancies are.  All of those thicknesses are positive in your picture.  The lenses in that picture will generate some aberrations. These aberrations mean a real ray trace (perhaps phydemo is doing that) will be different than a paraxial ray trace.